# Programmatically invoke the built-in camera control gestures on SceneView

Tags: swift, scenekit

Is there a way to programmatically invoke the the built-in camera control gestures on SceneView?

`sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true`

Comment: I cant think of the name at the top of my head but there is a a WWDC video that talks about this in great detail